# Как найти координаты 3 точки?

Tags: математика

[image: Изображение с линией и тремя точками, детали в описании к вопросу]

| Точка | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 8.05 | 8.1 | 0 |
| C | ? | ? | ? |

Расстояние от A до B — 10
Расстояние от B до C — 4

Как найти координаты точки С ?

Comment: а что у вас не получается? нужно найти единичный вектор, а помощью него можно будет найти точку С.

Comment: Похоже, жара на всех действует?... Все в плоскости (Я = 0) — обычная пропорция! (Xc - Xb)/(Xb-Xa) = 4/10. То же самое и для Y.

Answer (score 2):

Пользуемся теоремой Фалеса и всё: (10.87, 10.94, 0)

```js
var a = [1, 1, 0]
var b = [8.05, 8.1, 0]
var c = a.map((_, i) => b[i] + (b[i] - a[i]) / 10 * 4)
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Расстояние между точками в трёхмерной плоскости выражается через:
`d = √((x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)² + (z₂ - z₁)²)`
где `d` — расстояние между точками, `(x₁, y₁, z₁)` — координаты первой точки, `(x₂, y₂, z₂)` — координаты второй точки.

Т.к. Z для обоих точек равняется нулю, можно сократить до расположения на плоскости:
`d = √((x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²)`

Исходя из данной формулы, мы можем рассмотреть точки A (x = 1, y = 1) и B (x = 8.05, y = 8.1) и убедиться, что расстояние между ними равно 10:
`10 = √((8.05 - 1)² + (8.1 - 1)²)`
Без округления **10.005623418858**.

Теперь, учитывая, что расстояние между B и C равно 4, составим:
`4 = √((x₃ - 8.05)² + (y₃ - 8.1)²)`

Тут можно избавиться от корня возведением обеих частей в квадрат (расстояние от B до C):
`16 = (x₃ - 8.05)² + (y₃ - 8.1)²`

То же самое сделаем для расстояния от A до C (10+4), по итогу имеем систему из двух уравнений (расстояние в 14 тоже возводим):

```
196 = (x₃ - 1)² + (x₃ - 1)²
16 = (x₃ - 8.05)² + (y₃ - 8.1)²
```

Смотрим как решать систему из двух уравнений методом подстановки, алгебра, начальные классы.
У меня получилось:

```
x₃ = 11.0408335162876
y₃ = 10.7561089732637
```

Проверяем по формуле на нахождения расстояния (`d`) для точек B и C, получится 4.
Можно придать ещё чуть больше точности, ранее высчитывал точное расстояние между A и B, тогда:

```
196.157487350864 = (x₃ - 1)² + (x₃ - 1)²
16 = (x₃ - 8.05)² + (y₃ - 8.1)²

x₃ = 10.8684149199199
y₃ = 10.9384040126756
```

В таком случае на проверке расстояние будет идеально равно 4-ем.
Но, т.к. изначальное расстояние в **10** округлено, то и ответ можно абсолютно спокойно округлить до сотых, как и в условии для координат:

```
x₃ = 11.04
y₃ = 10.76
z₃ = 0
```

Comment: Эм.. Как ты округлил 10.8684 до 11.05, а 10.9384 до 10.75?

Comment: @Qwertiy округления для ответа, где расстояние берётся за 10, т.е. ответы чуть выше. Опечатка есть, да. Не 11.04, а 11.05.

Comment: @Qwertiy в общем странно, где-то я что-то неправильно посчитал, видимо, потому что для отрезка в 10 ответы разняться, а если в Фалеса поставить ранее высчитанное расстояние в 10.005623418858, то ответы сходятся  Как бы там не было, тоже вариант решения, пусть и более длинный.

Comment: Ты пишешь _x₃ = 10.8684149199199, y₃ = 10.9384040126756_ - если это округлить до двух знаков, то получится 10.87 и 10.94 как у меня. Я не понимаю, как ты их округляешь, чтобы получить 11.04 и 10.76.

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, я округляю `x₃ = 11.0408335162876` и `y₃ = 10.7561089732637` посчитанные на блок выше для расстояния в 10 (10+4 в квадрате), но видимо там намудрил с расчётами.